# How to update controls of a page from a "settings" flyout

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm building a metro style app. I designed a "settings" flyout where users can change the font of the textblocks contained in the HomePageView page of the app.

The font is chosen through a combobox that lists all system fonts. Once the font is choosen (in the combobox of the settings flyout) all the textblocks in the HomePageView page must be updated.

This is the style to update (located in standardstyles.xaml):

```
 <Style x:Key="timeStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="333.333"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
    </Style>
```

This is the code I use to update the textblock style and where I access the SetTextBlockFont property to update the textblocks appearance:

```
private void fontBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var res = new ResourceDictionary()
            {
                Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Common/StandardStyles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)

            };
            var style = res["timeStyle"] as Style;

            style.Setters.RemoveAt(2);
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Arial")));

            HomePageView homePageViewReference = new HomePageView();
            homePageViewReference.SetTextBlockFont = style;
        }
```

This is the SetTextBlockFont property in HomePageView.xaml.cs that updates a textblock (timeHour):

```
public Style SetTextBlockFont
        {
            set
            {
                timeHour.Style = value;
            }
        }
```

The app compiles without errors but when I click to a font in the combobox nothing happens. I think because I have to load the new instance of the HomePageView page homePageViewReference or because I have to reload the page or something similar.

I point out I can't use the Frame object or the NavigationService class because this is a metro app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your view or you can directly use DefaultViewModel given by LayoutAwarePage.

```
Class A:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region EventHandler
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
    public Style SetTextBlockFont
    {
        set
        {
            timeHour.Style = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SetTextBlockFont");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have still problems.

As I wrote above, the combobox in which I choose the font and the textblocks where I have to change the font are in different pages.

I'm not able to notify the change of the style between different pages.
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You can keep a singleton class or u can use app.xaml.cs and use a  Property. So when ever you navigate to a page using global property u can change the style in different pages.

Comment: Can you give me an example please? I have never used global properties and singleton classes. They are seldom used, I know. Thank you very much for your help